# Friendly ID - undefined method `slug=' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id, paper-trail-gem

I am using the gems Workflow, Paper Trail and Friend ID.

To track the state changes using Paper Trail, I have overridden the persist_workflow_state to explicitly update the workflow column, so that Paper Trail can capture the change.

https://github.com/geekq/workflow#integration-with-activerecord

```
def persist_workflow_state(new_value)
  update_attribute self.class.workflow_column, new_value
end
```

Now, I have introduced Friendly ID without slug column, and I get the error, upon reaching the above method.

```
undefined method `slug=' for #<ModelName:0x007f81cf342cd8>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Now, I have introduced Friendly ID without slug column

I don't know exactly what you mean here, but simply, it's like trying to start a car without the key

---

**FriendlyID**

The way [FriendlyID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) works is to use a `slug` (or other identifier) column to both create the slugged URL, and find based off the slugged ID:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
```

This allows the gem to find based off either the `id` or the `slug` attribute

If you miss out the `slug` column, this will prevent this from working, causing your error. The ways to fix this are:

1. Use the slug column
2. Create a slug attribute using `attr_accessor`

If you'd like to try the second option, you could try this:

```
#app/models/ModelName.rb
attr_accessor :slug
```

Comment: it worked but if we have slug column in db then why i'll need attr_accessor

Comment: The question asked about not having a slug column

Answer (score 6):

Richard Peck is correct that you have to add `slug` field.

But lot's of people got confused because FriendlyID generates `friendly_id_slugs` table which contains sluggable_id and sluggable_type field.

```
create_table "friendly_id_slugs", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "slug",                      null: false
t.integer  "sluggable_id",              null: false
t.string   "sluggable_type", limit: 50
t.string   "scope"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type", "scope"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type_and_scope", unique: true
t.index ["slug", "sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_slug_and_sluggable_type"
t.index ["sluggable_id"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_id"
t.index ["sluggable_type"], name: "index_friendly_id_slugs_on_sluggable_type"
end
```

Basically it generates friendly_id_slugs table for History Module.
Have a look at their documentation about **History__Avoiding_404_s_When_Slugs_Change** : http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#History__Avoiding_404_s_When_Slugs_Change

Answer (score 1):

Basic point is that, if you're using the friendly ID gem, then **you will need to add a slug column**, to the relevant ActiveModel table.

## Example: Add a slug to my Project model

Each Project has a name (attribute).

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
      extend FriendlyId
      friendly_id :name, use: :slugged        

      validates :name, :state, presence: true
end
```

#### 1. Run a migration to add a slug column

This can be done easily in rails:

```
 rails g migration AddSlugToProjects slug
```

#### 2. Don't forget the index!:

Make sure you add in an index on the slug column:

```
class AddSlugToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :projects, :slug, :string
    add_index :projects, :slug
  end
end
```

And now you're off to the races!